# java checked exception in a catch clause compilation error

Tags: java, exception

I was expecting an compilation error in the following program because of the throw statement in the catch block as IOException is a checked exception and it is not caught by another try block within the catch block. But I am getting "Hurray!" printed. Any explanation would be much appreciated.

According to JLS 11.2.3,
http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/exceptions.html

> It is a compile-time error if a method
>   or constructor body can throw some
>   exception type E when both of the
>   following hold:
>
> ```
> * E is a checked exception type
> * E is not a subtype of some type declared in the throws clause of the
> ```
>
> method or constructor.

```
import java.io.*;
public class Test{ 
    public static void main(String args[])
    {


        System.out.println(method()); 
    } 
    public static int method()
    {


        try{ 
            throw new Exception(); 
        }
        catch(Exception e){

            throw new IOException(); //No compile time error
        } 
        finally{

                    System.out.println("Hurray!");

        } 
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

That gives a compilation error using Eclipse's built-in Java compiler.

Same for the JDK 6.0 compiler.

What version of Java are you using that gives no compilation error?

Comment: Strange! I am using eclipse galileo too. No compilation error here.

Comment: Phew! Got it now after creating a new class file and copy pasting from  SO. I assume that it should have been because I was using using Exception before changing that to IOException and an automatic build was not taking place. Thanks for your reply and time.

Answer (score -1):

Maybe I'm missing something, but where is the [throws clause](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/essential/exceptions/declaring.html) in your program?

The source code as it appears now for method() does not contain a throws clause at the method header, just throw statements. Your quote from the JLS explicitly refers to throws clause.

Comment: As I commented on the other reply, It was a mistake on my part not forcing the build. Sorry, thanks for your time.